# Xorg.conf, which modules should be loaded for better performance?

Tags: linux, xorg, drivers, kernel-modules, graphics

In general what is supposed to be in the Module section of the Xorg.conf file in order to get maximum performance from a graphic card?

At the moment my Module section is empty... also because I didn't find any useful doc about modules.

...and if it matters, my graphic card is an ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series and I've already installed the Catalyst 12.6 drivers on my Ubuntu 12.04 box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know those days are over.

There are driver settings which are supposed to improve performance ... if Xorg does not use these settings anyways.

```
Option "ColorTiling" "1"
Option "EnablePageFlip" "1"
Option "AccelMethod" "EXA"
```

Don't know what they do. Got those off some forum a long time ago. The first 2 are supposed to improve 3D performance, the second 2D performance.

YMMV